# Replicating SIM causing device to download carrier bloatware but with my own apps

Tags: android, ios, sim-card

When you insert a sim card for the first time into a new device it causes the device often times to download carrier bloatware (not to be confused with manufacturer bloatware). What is the process by which the SIM causes this to happen? Is it because the card has a certain command built into it or is it because of a network protocol from the carrier (i.e. if this is the first time this phone or SIM is connecting to the network, cause it to download certain applications)?

I am attempting to reverse engineer this process of pushing apps to the device. I want to insert a custom SIM into a device (either Android or IOS) which connects it to a custom network which would then push an application install over to the device.

Comment: This must be an Android thing. As far as I know it doesn't happen and can't happen on iOS.  To push an app to iOS, the device must be under management by an MDM

Comment: That is entirely possible, I have not tested this on an IOS device but figured that it might be possible because it uses a SIM. An Android-only solution would be totally fine as well.